# Embedded Kafka Stream Exception during Parallel Processing

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When I execute my application to process data using Embedded Kafka Streams to run in parallel, i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "TopicInGroup-684d9a1a-35fd-40eb-9d76-d869eab30251-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [1_0] Fatal error while trying to lock the state directory for task 1_0
```

Note: Each kafka stream instance is executed in seperate JVM only.

Comment: kafka streams version used is 1.0.2

Comment: Please elaborate on what the central problem is and what have been tried, preferably with code and applicable configuration. Please add additional information; the question in its current state is very difficult to understand.

Comment: What is the full stack trace? This question is of low quality. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask